# Page Title and Left Nav Localization

Tags: 2010, localization, seo

My site in SP2010 is in 2 languages (English /French). English is the main language, so when I go to an individual pages properties I can edit the 'Title' field. Currently in my page layout I have this code in my 'PlaceHolderPageTitle':

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle">
     <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/
</asp:Content>
```

This shows the 'Title' field as the page title well. How can I specify the Page Title, and Left Navigation link as a french 'Title' when I select french as the language?

Comment: Have you already enabled MUI (not variations!) on your site? That should enable you automatically for each language.

Comment: Yes. I  have installed the language pack, and enabled the MUI. Problem is I can't set left nav or page titles in different languages. I tried changing to french, and then changing the page title. However that change it for both french and english versions.

Comment: gave you fixed this?
I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Since I was using a Publishing Site, I modified my site collection to use site variations. In this case each language will have its own page. ie. http://myserver/en-CA/Pages and http://myserver/fr-CA/Pages